# how to log all changes on an oracle database to apply them on an other database (using 9i)?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle9i

i need some advice about replacating the changes between 2 DBs, (pre-prodution & prodution), so i need to log all changes made on "Pre-Production" base to apply them later on the "Production" base, the log should contain all stransactions (cerations, insertions, updates, .....)

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to apply transactions from a pre-production database to a production database?  That seems like a poor architectural approach.  If you are going to promote a set of changes as part of a promotion process, those changes should be scripted out long before you get to a pre-production environment and you should just run the same script in both environments.

Comment: +1  Pre-production implies UAT or a similar environment.  Changes in such environments should be controlled and scripted.  Now, if we're talking about Development, that would be a different matter...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [ORacle Streams](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/Streams9i.php)? The implementation on 9i wasn't as good as more recent versions, but it might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the database to ARCHIVE LOG mode and the you can use RMAN to synchronize the DB